# Is there a way to scroll to top when esc key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html

How do i make it so that whenever i press `"esc"` it scrolls to the top? I have tried to use

```
<a name="top"></a>
<p>some text here.../p>
<a href="#top" id="backtotop">hi</a>
<script>
var input = document.getElementById("body");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 27) {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById("backtotop").click();
  }
});
</script>
```

but it doesn't work. If anyone could help me fix my code, that would be great! :)

Comment: You may find looking at the dev tools console in your browser would help you find some errors, for example you use getElementById but have no element with that id.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `document.body.scrollTop = 0` to scroll to the top of the page. Depending on which element actually has the scrollbar, it could be `document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0` too.

**Example:**

```js
var input = document.getElementById("body");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 27) {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>Top</div>
<input id = "body" type = "text"/>
```

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that when i press "esc" key it scrolls to the top

Comment: like this? <script>
  if (event.keyCode === 27) {
document.body.scrollTop = 0
  }
});
</script>

Comment: Pretty much. Check out my edit. I've put a snippet that illustrates it.

Comment: Glad I could help, @EricPan 

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.key == "Escape") {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.onkeydown = function(keyPressEvent) {
  if (keyPressEvent && keyPressEvent.key && (keyPressEvent.key === "Escape" || keyPressEvent.key === "Esc") && keyPressEvent.keyCode === 27) {
    console.log('Escape key pressed!');
    // put your logic here
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;

  }
};
```

```html
Escape Click Event
```

Note- Simple JS way to detect click event using [Key & keyCode](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp).

Comment: hmm... nothing happens when i click esc https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GJSAU1MNHOM8

Comment: @EricPan, I tested in my local machine! answer updated. Please check once again.